# \usepackage{polyglossia} problem with XeLaTeX

Tags: floats, xetex, polyglossia

I am a recent user of XeLaTeX and I face a problem with polyglossia package. All the chapters of my thesis are written in english except from the introductory chapter which is in greek. Thus, I use the polyglossia package in the preample

```
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{xltxtra}
 \usepackage{xgreek}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setmainlanguage[numerals=arabic]{greek}
 \setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}
 \newfontfamily\greekfont{FreeSerif}
 \usepackage{newunicodechar}
 \newunicodechar{ʹ}{{\dejavusans ʹ}}
```

The greek chapter begins with `\begin{greek}` and ends with `\end{greek}`. For the english chapters I use `\begin{english}` and `\end{english}` respectively.

My main problem is that when I insert a group of figures (e.g. four of them) in the text of an "english" chapter, the letters denoting the figures (a, b, c and d) appear in greek with an upper right tone.

```
 \begin{figure}[!htb]
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
   \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=0.8]{5_0002_jet1Pt}
    \caption{ }
   \end{center}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
   \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=0.8]{5_0003_jet2Pt}
    \caption{ }
   \end{center}  
  \end{subfigure}
 \bigbreak
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
   \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=0.8]{5_0004_muPt}
    \caption{ }
   \end{center}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
   \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=0.8]{5_0005_muEta}
    \caption{ }
   \end{center}
  \end{subfigure}
 \bigbreak
 \caption{Transverse momentum (p$_{T}$) of (a) leading jet, (b) subleading jet and (c) muon in truth level in LQ events. Plot (d) shows the pseudorapidity ($\eta$) distribution of muon.}\label{Py_versions_truth_comp}
 \end{figure}
```

This is the result

[image]

As you can see, the letters in the caption appear in english as they should. The problem is located only in the `figures`. Do you have any idea what 's going on? Is there any possibility that I have chosen wrong letter fonts which do not support greek text? Any suggestion is very very welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to make `mainlanguage` the english and `otherlanguage` the greek

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply. I should have mentioned that I have already done that and the result was to disappear all the figures letter from greek and english chapters. Plus, some pages with mix english ang greek text have been almost totally ruined.

Comment: Don't load the xgreek package. And set as main language the main language english.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is solved. Just for the record, I did not have to switch the two languages. It seems that the problem was coming only from the xgreek package.

Comment: yes xgreek is the main problem. But you should setup the languages in a sane way. If your main language is english, then don't lie to latex and pretend it is greek. I would also use \selectlanguage to switch the language and not an environment. I would also use babel instead of polyglossia, it is better maintained.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to write an answer or should this be closed as solved in comments?

Answer (score 1):

Don't load the `xgreek` package. It conflicts with other language packages like polyglossia.